# MessageHeader Attribute is not showing up - wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a `MessageContract` class with `MessageHeader` and `MessageBodyMember` properties in my WCF service.It is visible when I check the `wsdl` however, when I add to my uwp application only the `MessageBodyMember` is visible. I have checked the `reference.cs` which is added after I add service reference and `MessageHeader` is not visible in that.

**Contract in service**

```
[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
         if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**When I add service reference to UWP application**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="RemoteFileInfo", WrapperNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class RemoteFileInfo {
    
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
    public byte[] FileByteStream;
    
    public RemoteFileInfo() {
    }
    
    public RemoteFileInfo(byte[] FileByteStream) {
        this.FileByteStream = FileByteStream;
    }
}
```

**WSDL**

```
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFileInfo">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RemoteFileInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFileInfo_Headers">
<wsdl:part name="FileName" element="tns:FileName"/>
<wsdl:part name="Length" element="tns:Length"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Try to add the service reference again.

Comment: did that multiple times but did not help. Anyways, the work is no longer needed but the mystery remains unsolved :(